# jQuery-plugin in eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse, jquery-plugins

I was wondering if anyone knows of a plugin that I can install in eclipse Luna that contains the full jQuery functionality. It seems JSDT does not provide the full jQuery functionality. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of tern.java.

I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site), which provides a [support for jQuery](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-support) and too for [jQuery UI](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQueryUI-support), [jQuery Mobile](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQueryMobile-support), and [Bootstrap](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Bootstrap-support) (which is based on jQuery).

Comment: Hello @Angelo, I have tried your plugin. Seems I did something wrong. With the best intentions, is there a detailed tutorial about how do a correct configuration? I have installed the plugin, restarted the IDE, but any .js (based of course with Javascript with/without jQuery) remains without "auto complementation" support. Thanks...

Comment: I suggest you that you use Eclipse JEE Mars distribution. Please share your project which doesn't work (like github project)

Comment: Thanks, I have tested your work. Thanks a lot! it works!. Wonderful plugin!

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Aptana plugin in eclipse but after reading comments about how it messes up your codes, I decided to uninstall it (At a later time, I may play with it again just as a standalone). 
I decided to use the JSDT-jQuery 1.7 and I was surprised that I could actually add the jQuery 2.1 Library to my JavaScript Library. Everything is working fine right now with what I am building, so I am good for now.